# Using Marshal.SizeOf() method on a custom struct containing only value types

Tags: c#, .net

I created a simple struct which consists of two value types.

```
public struct Identifier
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Byte RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

Then I called `Marshal.SizeOf()` method on the custom struct `Identifier` using the following statements.

```
Identifier i = new Identifier();
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(i));   // output: 20
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(i.GetType()));   // output: 20
```

Why does `Marshal.SizeOf()` not return 17?
The following instructions show that a `Guid` object is 16 bytes and a Byte `object` is 1 byte.

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(g));   // output: 16
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(g.GetType()));   // output: 16

Byte t = 0;
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(t));   // output: 1
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(t.GetType()));   // output: 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the CLR is allowed to rearrange (which for simple structs it never does) and pad structs as it pleases. This is typically to keep it aligned to word boundaries when in memory.

If you don't like this behavior and want to change it, you can specify no packing as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=1)]
```

Comment: It's not the compiler that arranges structs in memory, it's the CLR. And Marshal.SizeOf returns the size *after marshalling to unmanaged memory*, not the size in managed memory as arranged by the CLR.

Comment: Why the CLR wants to keep the struct aligned to word boundaries when in memory? What are the consequences to disable the padding?

Comment: @enzom83: Say you have an array of `Identifier`, and you want to access the second `Guid`, it isn't byte aligned, so it may result in a multi-step read (read first word, read second word, combine wanted bits). By not providing a `StructLayout` you are telling the CLR that these kinds of details are not important to you.

Comment: Actually, there can be vast differences between how a struct is arranged in managed memory and how it is marshalled. For instance, a `char` takes 2 managed bytes but is usually marshalled to 1 byte. From this follows different padding, etc.

Comment: @dtb: I felt that including blittable would needlessly complicate the answer, but mentioned it in my comment. `char` is not blittable, and thus causes the two to not be the same, but `Guid` and `byte` are.

Comment: Right. I've overlooked "blittable" in your comment.

Comment: Therefore, the `Marshal.SizeOf()` method may return values _​​that are not expected_...

Comment: @enzom83: If you are looking for the unmanaged size of a struct, you will get the appropriate value. If you are looking for the managed size of a struct, you may not get that value. However there isn't really a use for the managed size, so I wouldn't worry about it. Note that blittable types are kept identical for performance reasons, so have identical managed and unmanaged formats.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Identifier` struct is padded with 3 bytes when copied to unmanaged memory for alignment reasons.

Comment: If I add a new field (for example a 4 byte `int`) on my custom struct, I get 24 from Marshal.SizeOf(), so `Identifier` seems always padded with 3 bytes. Indeed, if I have only a field in my custom struct, then the size is _correct_.

Comment: It depends on the fields if and where padding is added. A byte is not always padded with 3 bytes.

Comment: @enzom83: For example, if you added a *second* byte field *beside the first* then you'd find that the padding drops by one byte.

Answer (score 1):

CLR is not allowed to rearrange or pad structures. C#, Visual Basic, and C++ compilers apply the Sequential layout to structures by default. Even .NET 1.1 from 2003 (the oldest version with online documentation still available) did that, here’s [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=netframework-1.1#remarks) for that old documentation.

The actual reason why the compiler pads your structure with 3 bytes at the end is C compatibility. For unmanaged interoperability reason, unless one messes with `[StructLayout]` attribute, C# uses structure packing rules copy-pasted from C programming language.

GUID structure has a [first field of type int](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Guid.cs,31). And that’s the only reason why the compiler makes the size of your structure a multiple of 4 bytes.