# Size of object and other types

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to figure out if there is a resource somewhere that goes over the initial memory cost of `Object` in `.NET`. I realize different objects will have different sizes in memory (if you had a custom `Object`, for example), but I was more concerned as to what the initial memory cost was (the memory cost that all `Object` have initially, whether it is a custom object or not).

Basically, I am trying to write a helper method that will tell me the size (in bytes) of my custom class after I create an instance of it. To do so, I need to know the sizes of each of its properties and get the sum, but I am missing the 'overhead' so to speak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp

Comment: Are you looking for Marshal.SizeOf()?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003436 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220999 or even http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/

Comment: By "size in bytes", do you mean how much space is taken up in memory? `Marshal.SizeOf` and other techniques that measure the size of a serialization of your object do not accurately reflect how much space your object actually occupies in memory. Managed code doesn't provide a lot of insight into how things are laid out in memory or how much space they take up.